# Hyperbolic manifolds in the spatial circular restricted three body problem and topology definition

Tags: trajectory, astrodynamics

I am approaching the study of hyperbolic manifolds originated from Lagrange point periodic orbits in the spatial Circular Restricted Three Body Problem. I can read in many papers that what we obtain are tubes topological to two-dimensional manifolds (surfaces, to be less rigorous) embedded in the five-dimensional phase space (which accounts for the fact that we set everything at a certain Jacobi energy). However, I recently encountered a book where it says that the invariant manifolds of the spatial problem look like four-dimensional tubes in this five-dimensional phase space manifold.
Am I missing something?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: It will be easier to answer in a more helpful way if you add citations or links to the specific works you're reading. "I read somewhere that..." without links are sometimes not well-received